# server.context-path is appending twice in health endpoint in springboot admin /Eureka

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

In the health endpoint, server.context-path is appending twice.

server.context-path=/summary

Below health endPoint in SpringBoot Admin as well as in eureka:

http://localhost:8080/summary/summary/health

Comment: Do you also have any deployment file, where you define health url ?

Comment: It’s in our yml file.. we have several micro services , but we are getting the problem only in this particular case.. any insight would be great help..

Comment: can you please share your deployment yml file please. ?